# RecyclerView Order by specific details

Tags: android

I am making a Sweet order like App, I want to sort Orders according to order status like Placed(0), Shipped(1), OnTheWay(2), Delivered(3). If order status is 3(Delivered) I need to show that order at the bottom of the **recyclerview**, Currently I am using Stack Format to view orders, is it possible?

```
private void loadOrders(final String phone) {

        adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Request, OrderViewHolder>(
                Request.class,
                R.layout.order_layout,
                OrderViewHolder.class,
                requests.orderByChild("phone").equalTo(phone)
        ) {
            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(OrderViewHolder orderViewHolder, final Request request, final int i) {

                final String OrderId, OrderPhone, OrderTotal, OrderAddress, OrderComment, OrderUserName, OrderTime, OrderDate;

                OrderId = adapter.getRef(i).getKey();
                OrderPhone = request.getPhone();
                OrderStatus = Common.convertCodeToStatus(request.getStatus());
                OrderTotal = request.getTotal();
                OrderAddress = request.getAddress();
                OrderComment = request.getComment();
                OrderUserName = request.getName();
                OrderTime = request.getTime();
                OrderDate = request.getDate();

                if (request.getStatus().equals("3")){

                    orderViewHolder.orderStatusImage.setImageResource(R.mipmap.cupcake);
                    orderViewHolder.orderStatusImage.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);

                    orderViewHolder.txtOrderStatus.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    orderViewHolder.txtOrderDate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    orderViewHolder.txtOrderTime.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                    orderViewHolder.deliveredStatus.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                }

                orderViewHolder.txtOrderId.setText(String.format("Order Id :  %s",OrderId));
                orderViewHolder.txtOrderStatus.setText(String.format("Order Status :  %s",OrderStatus));
                orderViewHolder.txtOrderTime.setText(String.format("Order Time : %s",OrderTime));
                orderViewHolder.txtOrderDate.setText(String.format("Order Date : %s",OrderDate));

                if (dialog.isShowing()){
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }

                //Prevention for app crash when user clicks
                orderViewHolder.setItemClickListener(new ItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view, int position, boolean isLongClick) {
                        Intent orderDetail = new Intent(getActivity(), OrderDetail.class);
                        orderDetail.putExtra("OrderId",OrderId)
                                .putExtra("OrderPhone",phone)
                                .putExtra("OrderTotal",OrderTotal)
                                .putExtra("OrderAddress",OrderAddress)
                                .putExtra("OrderComment",OrderComment)
                                .putExtra("OrderUserName",OrderUserName)
                                .putExtra("OrderTime",OrderTime)
                                .putExtra("OrderDate",OrderDate)
                                .putExtra("OrderStatus",request.getStatus());

                        startActivity(orderDetail);
                    }
                });

            }
        };
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, what you want to do is to order the Orders in 0, 1, 2, 3 sequence.

Option 1: Sort the data before rendering the list. For example:

```
...
adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Request, OrderViewHolder>(
                Request.class,
                R.layout.order_layout,
                OrderViewHolder.class,
                requests.orderByChild("status").equalTo(phone)
        )
...
```

By ordering the data with status `requests.orderByChild("status").equalTo(phone)`, you list will show the Orders with status sequence. Of cause, with this change, your list is not ordering by phone number now. Please provide more of your code if you want to sort by both phone and status.

Option 2: If you can manipulate the data from firebase before creating the adapter, you can split the result into 2 list, one with status 0,1,2 and the other one with status 3. After that, you add the 2 list into the adapter one by one and attach the adaptor to the recycler view.

> Inside bottom of the Recyclerview just like Amazon/Flipkart Delivered Orders are shown at the bottom

So in this case, can you go with option 2. You can do 2 queries to firebase:

1. Query with status = 0,1,2  and keep `.orderByChild("phone").equalTo(phone)`
2. Query with status = 3 and keep `.orderByChild("phone").equalTo(phone)`

Then you append the 2 list into 1 list and create the adapter.

To optimise it further, you can query 1 time only and split the list to 2 list mentioned above locally in order not to query twice.

Comment: But i just want to show the delivered orders at bottom rest as it is

Comment: Can you provide some UI about `show the delivered orders at bottom` ? You mean inside the bottom of the listview or outside and below the listview?

Comment: Inside bottom of the Recyclerview just like Amazon/Flipkart Delivered Orders are shown at the bottom